# call GWT method from j2me

Tags: java, gwt, java-me

Is there any way to call gwt methods via j2me?something like that sending http request from any clients platforms to gwt server?
actually I want to send params from mobile(j2me) to gwt server and receive response from that to mobile device.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't call gwt server methods from j2me.

What you can do is use json to exchange data.

**For j2me**

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/

For GWT (well the server side)

You can use http://jackson.codehaus.org/ or http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Basically you need to make a servlet to handle the request.  Here is an example:  http://javathoughts.capesugarbird.com/2007/03/simplest-way-to-return-json-object.html

I will assume you have a GWT project and that you just want to use the server that you have to handle gwt requests to handle j2me as well.  It doesn't make sense otherwise as GWT runs as javascript in your browser.